# What grammar did the without null any command change to in Apache IoTDB Version 1.3?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

My original query statement in Apache IoTDB use `WITHOUT NULL ANY` command to filter which result columns cannot be null. However, when I updated my IoTDB version to 1.3.0, seems like this command cannot be used (I did not change any settings for the query statement and the system). Anyone know what grammar did this command change to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually specify which result columns cannot be null, and use command like `xx is not null and yy is not null`, and put them in the `where` or `having` clause of Apache IoTDB query statement.